# Unity3D How to Create Augmented Reality Without Marker?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I'm already make an augmented reality app that can read images marker, but I wonder if i can make augmented reality without marker in unity.
Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: I don't think you can. Thing is, the device has no idea of what kind of surfaces is it capturing (are they flat? vertical? is it an image on the wall or is it an actual landscape terrain?)

Comment: yeah i have seen like droid shooting in Google play, it uses own camera then the object can move around and we can move the camera to look the object. I wonder how to make that game?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe What you need is **SLAM**, I think. **Simultaneous Localization And Mapping**, and is markerless, just recognite and track the environment.

These are 2 videos about slam:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbaEw5-YvA0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YLzcWX-gWU

One is from kudan, one is from wikitude. If this feature is what you want. Then I am sure that what you need is **SLAM**.

You can get more from:

- [wikitude slam](http://www.wikitude.com/wikitude-slam/)
- [kudan](https://www.kudan.eu/)

And, vuforia is not adviced. In fact, **Smart Terrain** does recoginate the environment, it still need a marker.

Comment: The one from Kudan does not work with Unity 5.4 - I've reached out to them but no response yet.

Comment: Oh, what about wikitude?  Kudan is still not a big enough comoany, the fequency of update is not high. It seemed that what we can do is feedbacking and waiting. 

Comment: It was a trick getting it to work in Xcode but it eventually worked.

Comment: New note: SLAM is only offered to partners of Kudan, not users. So you can use Tracking and 3D, but not slam.

Comment: Update to the SLAM feature from Wikitude - there has been a considerable update to the engine in the past release. You might want to re-test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google ARCore, Vuforia or 8thWall SDKs. All of them have motion tracking or extended tracking. So you do not have to use markers. You can take a look at ARCore HelloAR example:

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/tutorials/hello-ar-sample

Answer (score -1):

you can using ARUnity. ARUnity is the Unity plugin for ARToolKit. (Well the marker would be some kind of image which is used for tracking. ARToolKit calls it NFT.)

You can download it here:
http://www.artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk
(Scroll down for the ARUnity download link)

Documentation is available here:
http://www.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=6_Unity:unity_getting_started

Best is, it is free and open-source :).

Comment: Although the information is basicly correct its off the point. NFT ist NOT markerless AR. There seems to be a generally confusion about that. With NFT you use a normal picture and use it as marker.